# sending few packet at the same time and get answer

Tags: scapy

I'm trying to sent 4 packet and get for each one a answer(like the "ping" tool on CMD), how do i do that?
the packet:

```
packet = IP(dst = "www.google.com")/ICMP()/"hi"
```

I know that i can sent like this: `send(packet, count=4)` but I need the answer to all of them.
`sr1(packet)` is sent it just one time and with `sr()` I didn't realize how I can use it to sent 4 packet and get answer...

I try to look here http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf on page 35

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `sr()` is for sending packets and receiving answers while `sr1()` is a variant that only returns the first answer for the packet sent. You can find more info [here](https://phaethon.github.io/scapy/api/usage.html#send-and-receive-packets-sr) and of course from the python's or scapy's interactive console by typing `help(sr1)`(or any other function) you can view details about the function:

```
sr1(x, filter=None, iface=None, nofilter=0, *args, **kargs)
    Send packets at layer 3 and return only the first answer
    nofilter: put 1 to avoid use of bpf filters
    retry:    if positive, how many times to resend unanswered packets
              if negative, how many times to retry when no more packets are answered
    timeout:  how much time to wait after the last packet has been sent
    verbose:  set verbosity level
    multi:    whether to accept multiple answers for the same stimulus
    filter:   provide a BPF filter
    iface:    listen answers only on the given interface
```

Now to send those packets 4 times in a row and get an answer for each one of them you could simply try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scapy.all import *

packet = IP(dst = "www.google.com")/ICMP()/"hi"
for _ in range(4):
    answer = sr1(packet)
    answer.show()
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!